# Returning a range of rows in DB2 (LIMIT X,Y equivalent)

Tags: database, db2

Im working with DB2 and I need to be able to return a limited set of results.
Ive figured out how to return the "TOP n" results with
"FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY"
But I cannot figure out how to get rows from X to Y.
mySQL equivalent is LIMIT X, Y

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS rownum, myLargeTable.*
 FROM myLargeTable
) AS tmp
WHERE rownum > 200000 AND rownum <= 200005;
```

[Source](http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/OLAPRowNumber)

Comment: Nice! It has been very helpful.